# Bootstrap overlay controls on Modal - scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a small project that incorporates bootstrap carousel controls on a modal so that a user can navigate from modal to modal without having to click out of it. It works perfectly, except one thing, after the first modal the user can no longer scroll down inside of an open modal.

I think it has something to do with me bringing the controls (.pull-front) in front of the body with `z-index`, however I need the control `<a>`s to be accessible and the only take up a tiny area on the edges of the screen. Not sure why they would cover the actual content? Any ideas? Thanks in advance hommies!

```
.pull-front {
  z-index:9;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I've made a codepen with the exact situation: **http://codepen.io/simplecreatif/pen/bWQYVQ**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because bootstrap remove `.modal-open` class from body when you click `next` or `prev` buttons. You have to add `modal-open` class to body if modal is open.

So add this code in your js

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    if($('.modal.in').length)
    {
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    }
});
```

here is the link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmwygL

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about that part because the actual modal was visible! Makes complete sense now, thank you so much mate!

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad guess, but it's actually because when you click `btn-next` you lose the class `modal-open` on `body`. It needs that class to work properly.